# ReactJS won't display images which import from JSON

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a JSON file that contains all my image datas, I import this JSON file to my ReactJS component, I use map() to loop through the image array to my image list, but the images was not display on my webpage. (I checked the image path, nothing wrong with it.)

Here is my JSON files

[image]

Here is my ReactJS component

[image]

Comment: What can you see if you press F12 and then the network tab? Do you see the browsing trying to get images and are there any errors? Also please just post code instead of images, posting images is a sure way to get downvoted.

Comment: Add code data or json or layout code.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.